# i want to create a file with the person's name, how can i get no errors?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i can't get it, it says "Extension 'cogs.money' raised an error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (money.py, line 26)"

```
@commands.command()
        async def money(self, ctx, member):
            #how do i get the people who message, name

        open(member, '.txt', 'a').close()

      if os.stat(member, '.txt').st_size == 0:
          moneyfile=open(member, '.txt', 'w')
          moneyfile.write('40')
          moneyfile.close()
      else:
        readfile=open(member, '.txt', 'r').read()
        points=readfile
        int(points)
        await ctx.send(points)
```

Comment: The error has to do with your code. You are not indenting it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The error states exactly what is wrong. Your code is resulting in Indentation Error. Fix your spacing on line 26 and that error will go away.

```
"Extension 'cogs.money' raised an error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (money.py, line 26)"
```